# Decode Magstripe Audio with 1 channel, 8 bits and 10000 sample rate

Tags: python, audio, magnetic-cards

I followed [this description](https://andrewmohawk.com/2012/05/29/magnetic-stripes-part-1/) to learn how to create a magnet stripe card reader, and I got a pretty good result with samples provided [here](http://alcrypto.co.uk/magstripe/).

However, the samples provided two audio files which were encoded with 1 channel, 16 bits and 44100 sample rate, and worked great with the codes provided inside the folder (`dab.py`), but when I tested with an audio I had which was encoded with 1 channel, 8 bits and 10000 sample rate, the codes gave me this error:

**"unpack requires a bytes object of length 2"**

How should I modify the code to avoid this error?

Comment: what process created your audio file with a 10k sample rate ?  44100 is the standard sample rate, 10000 is decidedly non standard ... have you tried playing that same audio file using a normal audio player like vlc ? I am trying to understand whether the issue is in the synthesis of that audio file or in its rendering ( playback )

Comment: actually I got the audio file with the sample rate I mentioned from my friend that he said he took it from a card skimmer. I am sorry that I could not show you that file because it contained actual card information. Let's talk about the skimmer I mentioned earlier, it was super small that it could fit an ATM card slot without being noticed. I think people who installed it must use some technique to compress the audio file so that they could record an audio for a longer time.